# Duplicate packets when receiving multicast traffic on multiple interfaces

Tags: c, linux, networking, routes, multicast

My goal is to have a seperate multicast socket for each linux interface, so on each socket I'm calling:

```
int join_multicast(int fd, int if_index, const char *local_ifc_address)
{
    struct ip_mreqn mreq;
    MEMSET_ZERO(mreq);

    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(MY_MULTICAST_ADDR);
    mreq.imr_address.s_addr   = inet_addr(local_ifc_address);
    mreq.imr_ifindex      = if_index;

    if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&mreq,
               sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        ERROR("IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed (fd: %d): %s", fd,
            strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But then this failed with no such device
After googling to fix this I have to call

```
route -n add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 224.0.0.0 dev <ifc>
```

on each interface.

The issue: after running the program, a single packet coming from each interface is somehow written to each socket.
So in short, the multicast packet comes to eth0, and I can read both from sockets associated with eth0 and eth1, which makes it impossible to distinguish the source interface.

I've tried SO_BINDTODEVICE, and it did not help.

Has anyone had a similar issue?
When running Tcpdump on e.g. eth0 I can see only one, valid multicast packet arriving

edit:

Ok, I've solved the issue. I've been using SO_BINDTODEVICE with level IPPROTO_IP instead of SOL_SOCKET.

But still, is this valid behavior of IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP with if_index directly specified?